# Display form fields depending on user

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

So I have a social network where users can post thinks. I would like to incorporate a blog system into the same `feed` app instead of making blog its own app. I was thinking that if I (or someone with adequate permissions) wanted to make a blog post they could use the same form used by everyone to make a post, however since they have higher permissions they would be shown an extra option on the form that allows them to make it a blog post. and on the blog page I would just filter out to only have posts with `blog_post` set to true to be shown.

I tried to do this with a simple if statement in the forms.py however I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/garrettlove/Desktop/evverest/evverest/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    from feed import views
  File "/Users/garrettlove/Desktop/evverest/feed/views.py", line 4, in <module>
    from feed.forms import PostForm,CommentForm
  File "/Users/garrettlove/Desktop/evverest/feed/forms.py", line 7, in <module>
    class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 248, in __new__
    "needs updating." % name
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form PostForm needs updating.
```

forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserPost

        if User.username == 'garrett':
            fields = ('title','image','post_body','blog_post')
        else:
            fields = ('title','image','post_body')

        widget = {
            'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'post-title'}),
            'post_body':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'post-body'}),
        }
```

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

# Create your models here.
class UserPost(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='userpost',null=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=False)
    post_body = models.TextField(max_length=1000,blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_pics',blank=True)
    blog_post = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-post_date']

    def publish(self):
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('index')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404,redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from feed.models import UserPost,UserComment
from feed.forms import PostForm,CommentForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from braces.views import SelectRelatedMixin

from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,ListView,
                                    DetailView,CreateView,
                                    UpdateView,DeleteView)

User = get_user_model()

# Create your views here.

##Posts Views
class HomeView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    login_url = 'account_login'
    model = UserPost

class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    login_url = 'users:user_login'
    redirect_field_name = '/userpost_list.html'
    model = UserPost
    form_class = PostForm

    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super(CreatePostView, self).form_valid(form)

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = UserPost
    post_comments = UserComment.objects.all()
    context = {
            'post':model,
            'comments':post_comments,
            }

class UpdatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    model = UserPost
    fields = [
            'title',
            'post_body',
            ]
    template_name_suffix = '_edit_form'

    def get_success_url(self):
        postid = self.kwargs['pk']
        return reverse_lazy('index')

@login_required
def DeletePost(request,pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(UserPost,pk=pk)
    post.delete()
    return redirect('index')

##Comments Views
@login_required
def add_comment_to_post(request,pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(UserPost,pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.author = request.user
            comment.save()
            return redirect('feed:post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request,'feed/comment_form.html',{'form':form})

@login_required
def comment_remove(request,pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(UserComment,pk=pk)
    post_pk = comment.post.pk
    comment.delete()
    return redirect('feed:post_detail',pk=post_pk)


##BLOG VIEWS
class BlogView(ListView):
    model = UserPost
```

Comment: add your view code please

Comment: @BearBrown Just added the views

Answer (score 2):

in your view need add user to kwargs:

```
class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    # Your code here
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(CreatePostView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})
        return kwargs
```

after it use `__init__` method (i correct it with Daniel solution)

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserPost
        fields = ('title','image','post_body','blog_post')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not user.username == 'garrett':
            self.fields.pop('blog_post')
```

Comment: The blog_post field still show regardless of if it is me or not.

Comment: Give me a type error: `TypeError at /feed/new/
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'`

Answer (score 1):

This can't possibly work in this way. This is all evaluated when the class is defined, long before there are any users. And `User` is the class itself, not an instance of it; `User.username` is just a CharField object, not an actual username.

Instead, you need to set the full list of fields as default, but in the form's `__init__` method you take the current user and modify the actual fields as necessary.

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserPost
        fields = ('title','image','post_body','blog_post')
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user.username != 'garrett'
            del self.fields['blog_post']
```

Comment: The blog_post field still show regardless of if it is me or not.

Comment: Are you actually passing the user to the form when you instantiate it?

Comment: No, why do I need to?

Comment: What sort of a question is that? You specifically want a form that behaves differently depending on the user. So of course you need to pass it the user.

Comment: Ok, I'm a beginner though so that makes sense but I didn't know that had to be done.